# CodePipeline invoking Lambda with a simple println taking up to 10 minutes

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-codepipeline

I'm using CodePipeline and have a Lambda isolated in an Action/Stage to make an http request after the deployment starts.

I can see on logs and on Monitoring tab that it finished in 500ms or so, but the Action keeps waiting for 10 minutes to end.

I have already tried the following:

- Python 3 and NodeJS 8.
- Dummy functions with only a println
- Inside and outside VPC
- 1GB of ram
- limiting timeout from 1 seconds to 10
- with other actions, stages
- removing, creating again, ...

My current code is the hello word:

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    // TODO implement
    return 'Hello from Lambda!';
};
```

In all those cases, the Action/Stage still keep taking 10 minutes to finish.
Am I missing something? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call either `PutJobSuccessResult` or `PutJobFailureResult` from your Lambda function to notify CodePipeline that your action is complete.

Here's an example: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/actions-invoke-lambda-function.html#actions-invoke-lambda-function-create-function

Comment: Thank you so much. I did it and resolved my question, but it still waiting 2 or 6 minutes to finish. I really think this number can be cut as it only really takes 200~800ms to run the request itself.

Comment: Tim's answer to a similar question had some additional explanation of why this is necessary: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52062824/31304