# Lambda function never succeeds in codepipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-codepipeline

When I run my Lambda function in Codepipeline it ends properly and does what I want as I can see **in logs**, but it **never succeeds in pipeline**. It just shows *In Progress* when actually my Lambda function does its job in logs.

What am I missing? Maybe I need to send *'putJobSuccessResult'* as shown [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/actions-invoke-lambda-function.html?icmpid=docs_acp_console#actions-invoke-lambda-function-create-function) to CodePipeline? But if so then why if it's not a custom action?

And what are custom actions at all? What is the difference between them and non-custom actions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Maybe I need to send 'putJobSuccessResult' as shown here to CodePipeline?

Yes, you need to call putJobSuccessResult from your Lambda function.

> But if so then why if it's not a custom action?

This tells CodePipeline that your Lambda function is finished, and what to do next.

CodePipeline has a feature where if you pass a 'continuation token' then CodePipeline will re-invoke your function and pass the state in the continuation token to the next invocation. This allows you to have actions running longer than the Lambda invocation timeout. You can pass this info when you call putJobSuccessResult.

Also, it separates "failing an action" from "failing the function". This allows you to fail the action without failing the lambda function. This is desirable because Lambda has a [retry behavior](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/retries-on-errors.html) if the function fails.

> And what are custom actions at all?

With a custom action you need your own code to call PollForJobs, which typically runs on eg. a long running EC2 instance. The Lambda invoke action will call a Lambda function without you having to run your own instance / host.

Comment: Can you please tell me more about this continuation token or give url with info about it, cause I didnt find anything. What can/must you put in this continuation token when sending it? When codepipeline re-invoke your function does that mean that my function will simply run its code one more time, but why do I need that? What else codepipeline can do with it? What is the state of continuation token?

Comment: And also how do you know all of that? Cool webiste or docs? Some webinars? Simply experimenting?

Comment: @PetroKoval I'm an engineer from the AWS CodePipeline team and I wrote parts of the Lambda integration ;) All this information should be documented publicly though. For example, you can find details on the Lambda integration and continuation tokens here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/actions-invoke-lambda-function.html

Comment: Ok, thanks again)) Tell please the guys who rule the docs that the docs can be slightly better that now) (no offense)

Comment: @TimB, is there a way to set a timeout before the next call of Lambda function with continuation token included? For example I know that a process is long beforehand so it doesn't make sense to call Lambda 20 times per minute. How can I adjust it? And also what is a default behavior? I can't find any documentation on that.

Comment: @Dobby007 you can't adjust the continuation token interval (from memory it's 30 seconds), but you also don't have to call putJobSuccessResult() from the same Lambda function. For an asynchronous process it might be better to not call putJobSuccessResult() from Lambda and call it when the long running thing finishes instead. For example, have the Lambda put a message in a queue, and have the queue processor call putJobSuccessResult() without a continuation token when it processes the message and finishes the long running work.

Comment: @TimB, it will involve some coupling between a long-running process and the pipeline. However just because I'm interested and I haven't tested it yet, won't the pipeline move to the next step if I don't call putJobSuccessResult() from the Lambda? It will simply hang on this step till I call the method and not even call the Lambda again, did I understand you correctly? Seems a little awkward to me.

Comment: @Dobby007 it could be worth opening a new question because I might not be following your use-case. I assumed you wanted the pipeline to wait until your long-running process finishes. If that's not the case then there might be another way that works.

Comment: @TImb, you understood my initial question correctly. I just noticed that your solution on how to adjust the timeout will involve some level of undesirable coupling which is architecturally incorrect. And there was another question about CodePipeline behavior but if you don't know for sure, that's ok.